# Get a list of posts with associated meta_value

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop

Recently I began to use the Custom Fields. 
I would like to display a listing of posts which contains the meta_key "oldtimer" and also get the corresponding meta_value.

**Here is the expected result:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Title of post 1</td>
    <td>OLD-39283</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Title of post 2</td>
    <td>OLD-22445</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Title of post 3</td>
    <td>OLD-32145</td>
</tr></table>
```

Here is the PHP code I have for now. I don't know how to get the **meta_value** for **each post**:

```
$args =
    array(
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'title',
    'meta_key'               => 'oldtimer'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<table>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<tr><td><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</td>';
        echo '<td>meta_key</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Here is the information on SQL side:
[image]

Is anyone has an idea? Any suggestion about this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch the post meta manually within the loop as follows:

```php
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'oldtimer', true );
```

That should get you the correct value. Hope it helps

Comment: It's working as expected. Thank you :)